# Firebase Realtime Databse - Updating Multiple Tables

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I need some help understanding how to update multiple tables at the same time.

I have a basic update form:

[image]

This form updates a User and Record table (linked by User UID):

[image]

This is fine, however, when I update Level/Score again:

[image]

Instead of updating the existing Record, it creates a new one:

[image]

I know I'm doing something wrong, I just needed it pointed out.
I suspect there's a much more efficient way of doing this.

One more thing, the form is only loading the Name and Email in the EditTexts and I don't know why (I'm trying to load all 4).

[image]

Here's my Main Activity code where these updates take place.
I have removed all but necessary code:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var mUser: Users
    private lateinit var mRecord: Records
    private lateinit var mAuth : FirebaseAuth
    private lateinit var mDatabase: DatabaseReference

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference

        mDatabase.child("Users").child(mAuth.currentUser!!.uid)
             .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener {

                    override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {
                        TODO("Not yet implemented")
                    }

                    override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {
                        if (p0.hasChildren()) {
                            val user = p0.getValue(Users::class.java)
                            val record = p0.getValue(Records::class.java)

                            et_main_name.setText(user?.name)
                            et_main_email.setText(user!!.email)
                            et_main_level.setText(record?.level)
                            et_main_score.setText(record?.score)
                        }
                    }
             })

            bt_update_button.setOnClickListener {
                val name = et_main_name.text.toString().trim()
                val email = et_main_email.text.toString().trim()

                val uid = mAuth.currentUser!!.uid
                val level = et_main_level.text.toString().trim()
                val score = et_main_score.text.toString().trim()

                updateUser(name, email)
                updateRecord(uid, level, score)
                finish();
            }
    }

    private fun updateUser(name: String, email: String?) {
        val user = Users(name, email)
        mDatabase.child("Users").child(mAuth.currentUser!!.uid).setValue(user)
    }

    private fun updateRecord(uid: String, level: String, score: String?) {
        val record = Records(uid, level, score)
        mDatabase.child("Records").push().setValue(record)
    }
}
```

## **Edit 1**

Thank you, the code you provided sets UID as a parent in the Records table and ensures the correct child record is updated. I have also removed uid as a child in the Records table.

This function:

```
private fun updateRecord(level: String, score: String?) {
        val record = Records(level, score)
        mDatabase.child("Records").child(mAuth.currentUser!!.uid).setValue(record)
    }
```

Now updates like this:

[image]

Also, all 4 EditTexts are now populated, but using two functions, like this:

```
mDatabase.child("Users").child(mAuth.currentUser!!.uid)
            .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener {

                override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {
                    TODO("Not yet implemented")
                }

                override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {
                    if (p0.hasChildren()) {
                        val user = p0.getValue(Users::class.java)
                        et_main_name.setText(user?.name)
                        et_main_email.setText(user!!.email)
                    }
                }
            })

mDatabase.child("Records").child(mAuth.currentUser!!.uid)
            .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener {

                override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {
                    TODO("Not yet implemented")
                }

                override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {
                    if (p0.hasChildren()) {
                        val record = p0.getValue(Records::class.java)
                        et_main_level.setText(record?.level)
                        et_main_score.setText(record?.score)
                    }
                }
            })
```

How can I combine these into one function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because `Firebase` generate random string `-M4n2Tz9Ci_7anyOXOLo` & `-M4n308C7tUZOIF9YCBP` with your `mDatabase.child("Records").push().setValue(record)`. It is different random string, so it makes new row.
You also only got 2 data because you don't know this random string

[Not Sure, maybe ignored this] Why it generate random string? Because you push some values to `Record` which is like main folder(?). That some values (level, score, uid) need to put in subfolder. IDK, i am not quite sure to explain this

to solve this. Try:

```
private fun updateRecord(uid: String, level: String, score: String?) {
    val record = Records(uid, level, score)
    mDatabase.child("Records").child(mAuth.currentUser!!.uid).setValue(record)
    // mDatabase.child("Records").child(uid).setValue(record) /* or this should be fine i guess? */
}
```

The DB now should be like this (below). And should be updated because now the `UID` is same

```
writedb-1a4bb
| -- Records
|    | -- <UID>
|          | -- level : "level 10"
           | -- score : "10"
           | -- uid : "<UID>" // maybe you don't need this anymore
| -- Users (same...)
```

Comment: Thank you, this makes sense to me now. Let me change a few things and report back.

Comment: Ok yes I understand now. Thank you. I may or may not need UID as a parent in the Records table, that will depend on my relationships. If you can please see Edit 1 in my post. I am able to display all 4 fields in the EditTexts, but is there a way to combine that into one function?